# Can I regenerate a CSRF token for a Graphql mutation in SilverStripe admin?

Tags: javascript, graphql, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm sending a mutation from react in the SilverStripe pages admin area but users are seeing a CSRF error with the message `"Invalid CSRF token"`. However, they still appear to be logged in (if they are not I get instead `"Authentication required"` in the error).

Is there a way to re-fetch/regenerate a CSRF token from Javascript? Eg an endpoint that a logged in user can use to get a new token?

I had a look at the `CSRFMiddleware.php` where the error originates and did a general search in core for CSRF, but I can't see a related endpoint which would allow me to do this.

UPDATE: I can reliably reproduce this by loading an admin page, then removing the session cookie, and logging back in on a separate tab. So the CSRF in JS memory becomes invalid.

Comment: Interesting problem. I think there's certainly a case to be made for the GraphQL module to offer a `securityID` query out of the box, since we already offer CSRF protection by default. The question becomes how do you prevent that token from becoming stale in an application. With forms, it's easy, because the token is rendered at load time, but in the context of an SPA, you only get one load, and one injection into the JS memory. Just thinking out loud, it would have to be some kind of polling event, but deleting the session wouldn't necessarily trigger a refresh.

Comment: I was thinking that you could do this on expiry - so in the case of an invalid error, fetch a new token and then retry the mutation?

Comment: I thought the SecurityID could be retrieved from the redux store under `config`, is that not what you're asking about?

Comment: It's still in memory, though. If your session breaks, there's no way to get a new one outside or refreshing the browser.

Comment: CMS normally does a "ping" request every X minutes to keep the session up. If you remove the sesson cookie you basically "log out", so how should SilverStripe know that you're logged in as a user?